# Вызов функции в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь вставить гамбургер меню в шаблон вордпресс, но не могу понять куда нужно вставлять такого рода вызов функции:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
```

$(this).closest("body").toggleClass("active");
});

Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

[Здесь находится код меню](https://codepen.io/netfuel/pen/rIlnB/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой код надо вставлять в свои js-скрипты и подключать их через `wp_enqueue_script()`

Ваш скрипт в файле должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("body").toggleClass("active"); });
});
```

Comment: я так пробовала но почему то не получается. Именно такие вызовы не получается. Может что то я не так делаю, вроде все как обычно

Comment: покажите ваш код php и js

Comment: wp_enqueue_style( 'burger-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/burger.css' ); wp_enqueue_script( 'burger-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/burger.js', array(), '', false );  это function.php   я сделала js туда добавила вызов как вы сказали. Ссылка на сам код который хочу вставить вверху в вопросе

Comment: это кусок html который пытаюсь вставить в header.php    
               <a href="#" class="button">
    <span class="menu">
      <b>menu</b>
    </span>
  </a>
  
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
              </div>

        </div>
  
        </div>
    <!--    container-fluid -->
 <div id="content" class="site-content">

Comment: какой бургер не поставлю все криво работают. то ли скрипты конфликтуют то ли скрипты я не в том порядке ставлю и они не отрабатывают

Comment: Вы обернули скрипт в `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { .... });` ?

Comment: нет я просто взяла скопировала и вставила в скрипт

Comment: $(".button").click(function(){
 $(this).closest("body").toggleClass("active");
});

Comment: можете показать как этот код обернуть , как он должен в итоге выглядеть

Comment: Дополнил ответ...